# My Dragon Head fell into the void. How can I get another one?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is there any way to get another dragon head? Mine fell into the void of the end city and I can't get it back.

Comment: @Robbie How did you know that this question should be tagged [tag:minecraft-console] as opposed to [tag:minecraft]

Comment: In the unedited question they had "PS4 edition" in the title. @pppery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can respawn the Ender Dragon by placing 4 end crystals on the center of each side of the portal. After you defeat the Ender Dragon again a new End Gateway will open and you can get a new end city.

You could also continue searching the end islands trying to find a new end city but this could result in you losing your portal and getting stuck in the end.

Comment: Your answer is better so I'm going to delete mine.